# Displaying message multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

I have following code.

```
<fieldset id="test">
    <label><b>(2)</b> Open Sub-tasks</label>
    <div class="table-holder">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:40%;">Location/Problem</th>
                <th style="width:30%;">Assignment</th>
                <th class="align-right" style="width:30%;">Due Date</th>
            </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody id="tbody">
            <tr>
                <td>Bathroom, Plumbing</td>
                <td>Johnny Fixalot</td>
                <td class="align-right">03/14/2017</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <ul class="multi-list tabs">
            <li class="width-50 sub_task_complete">
                <a class="first">Mark Complete</a></li>
            <li class="width-50 sub_task_complete">
                <a class="last even">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="table-holder">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
               <th style="width:40%;">Location/Problem</th>
               <th style="width:30%;">Assignment</th>
               <th class="align-right" style="width:30%;">Due Date</th>
            </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody id="tbody">
            <tr>
                <td>Bathroom, Plumbing</td>
                <td>Johnny Fixalot</td>
                <td class="align-right">03/14/2017</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <ul class="multi-list tabs">
            <li class="width-50 sub_task_complete">
                <a class="first">Mark Complete</a></li>
            <li class="width-50 sub_task_complete">
                <a class="last even">Delete</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
</fieldset>
```

As per this code, its displaying 2 tasks with options Mark Complete and Delete respectively. When any option is selected that particular "li" gets selected class. I am trying to validate whether any options selected or not and trying to display an error message.
My trial code is-

```
$('ul.multi-list').each(function(){ 
 if($('li.sub_task_complete.selected').length == 0){
    $('fieldset#test').addClass('error');
    $('fieldset#test .table-holder').after('<span class="oops">Please select an option for completing or deleting sub task.</span>');
 }
});
```

Its displaying the message 4/5 times. I want to display a message after each table holder **only once if it's not selected**.

Note: There can be multiple fieldsets with ul.multi-list class hence sub_task_complete class of li is only the distinguishing factor.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, after your comment on my first answer I get what you're doing. In this case you want to use .closest. Pretty sure this does what you're after.

```
// Iterate through the lists individually
$('ul.multi-list').each(function(){
    // Set the errors variable for this list to 0
    var errors= 0;
    // Iterate through the li's in this list
    // Increment errors if any of the tasks are missing .selected
  $(this).find('li').each(function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass("selected")){
    errors++;
        }
    })

    // Check if this list has 2 errors meaning neither 
    // li has .selected and add the error class and message to 
    //this list only
  if( errors ==2 ) {
    $(this).closest('.table-holder').addClass('error');
    $(this).closest('.table-holder').after('<span class="oops">Please select an option for completing or deleting sub task.</span>');
  }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4qprwk3y/

Comment: as soon as I select one of the options for the first div and not for the second div then it's not working. It should show a message for second div or whichever for which no option selected.

Comment: @PranavUnde Check the answer now, I misunderstood what you were trying to do here.

Comment: eh, it was still wrong, updated now works as you can see in the added fiddle. Just add the selected class to whichever li you like to see it work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterate through all li option you can use inbuilt jQuery function like this to achieve your goal:

```
if($('li').filter('.selected').length == 0)
{
e.preventDefault();
alert('please select atleast one option');
}
```

[Here you can see an example](https://jsfiddle.net/9v7mLv3v/)

Comment: Got e undefined. So I tried $(this) then it gives preventDefault is not a function...

Comment: For your case i guess no need of "e.preventDefault". Since in my example i was using submit type button that is why i added "e.preventDefault".